# Calling API from angular "results in undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

am struggling to figure out, what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to call a rest API from my angular code, but it results in "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

My **clients.ervice.ts** code looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Clients } from './clients.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientsService {

  clientsUrl="http://localhost:21063/api/clints

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
getAllClients():Observable<Clients[]>{
    return this.http.get<Clients[]>(this.clientsUrl);

}
```

My code in the **client.component.ts**

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private Service: ClientsService) { }
  clients:Clients[];
  ngOnInit() {

this.Service.getAllClients()
      .subscribe(data => this.clients=data);
```

and this is **model.ts**

```
export class Clients {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    phone:string;
    address:string;
    type:string;
    account:number;
    nots:string;
    branchId:number;
}
```

finaly my templets:

```
                  <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of clients"></tr>
                        <td>{{item.id}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.name}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.phone}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.address}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.account}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.nots}} </td>

                    </tbody>
```

thanks in advance for any help to fix and understand this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem go easy on yourself, you forgot to make the tr element wrap all the td elements

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of clients">
      <td>{{item.id}} </td>
      <td>{{item.name}} </td>
      <td>{{item.phone}} </td>
      <td>{{item.address}} </td>
      <td>{{item.account}} </td>
      <td>{{item.nots}} </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```